# Qmail & SPF - deciphering the log files

Tags: email, spf, spam-filter

Can someone help me decipher whats going on in these log files? I've added my own comments there, but as I'm not experienced mail admin I could do with an experienced eye ;)

The bit which gets me is that the SPF section causes the message rejection, even though the domain the mail is being sent from is a very, very well known company. Is it simply that they don't have SPF headers set on their domain?

If so.. what are the safest settings I could use on my server to allow legit email but block spam?

I've got domainkeys, SPF and spamhaus blacklists running, but SPF seems to be causing some problems.

Thanks a lot for any help :)

```
Remote mailserver connects and begins negotiation

Oct 20 18:30:59 msvsc01-g09np postfix/smtpd[29264]: connect from unknown[192.208.34.37]
Oct 20 17:30:59 msvsc01-g09np postfix/smtpd[29264]: NOQUEUE: client=unknown[192.208.34.37]
Oct 20 17:30:59 msvsc01-g09np postfix/smtpd[29269]: BD5B9292AF1: client=unknown[192.208.34.37]
Oct 20 18:30:59 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: check handlers for addr: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com 
Oct 20 18:30:59 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: check handlers for addr: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.com 
Oct 20 18:30:59 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: check handlers for addr: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.com 
Oct 20 18:30:59 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: Processing handlers... 
Oct 20 18:30:59 msvsc01-g09np before-remote[29268]: check handlers for addr: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com 
Oct 20 18:30:59 msvsc01-g09np before-remote[29268]: check handlers for addr: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.com 
Oct 20 18:30:59 msvsc01-g09np before-remote[29268]: check handlers for addr: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.com 
Oct 20 18:30:59 msvsc01-g09np before-remote[29268]: Processing handlers... 

Qmail handling

Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: hook_dir = '/usr/local/psa/handlers/before-queue'
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: recipient[3] = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.com 
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: handlers dir = '/usr/local/psa/handlers/before-queue/recipient/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.com '
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: call_handlers: call executable = '/usr/local/psa/handlers/info/20-drweb-MZX9NW/executable'
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: handlers_stderr: PASS
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: call_handlers: PASS during call '/usr/local/psa/handlers/info/20-drweb-MZX9NW/executable' handler
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: recipient[4] = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.com'
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: handlers dir = '/usr/local/psa/handlers/before-queue/recipient/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.com'
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: call_handlers: call executable = '/usr/local/psa/handlers/info/20-drweb-FoRKet/executable'
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: handlers_stderr: PASS
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: call_handlers: PASS during call '/usr/local/psa/handlers/info/20-drweb-FoRKet/executable' handler
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: call_handlers: call executable = '/usr/local/psa/handlers/info/10-spf-d7R8jL/executable'

DrWeb Virus Check

Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np qmail-queue[29271]: scan: the message(drweb.tmp.j0zApu) sent by xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com to rcpts is passed

SPF Checking

Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np spf filter[29273]: Starting spf filter... 
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np spf filter[29273]: Error code: (2) Could not find a valid SPF record 
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np spf filter[29273]: Failed to query MAIL-FROM: No DNS data for 'cadbury.com'. 
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np spf filter[29273]: SPF result: none 
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np spf filter[29273]: SPF status: REJECT

SPF Checked and Failed?! = Message rejected. 504 error returned.

Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: handlers_stderr: REJECT
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: call_handlers: REJECT during call '/usr/local/psa/handlers/info/10-spf-d7R8jL/executable' handler
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-queue[29266]: call_handlers: stop call handlers from dir '/usr/local/psa/handlers/before-queue/global'
Oct 20 17:31:00 msvsc01-g09np postfix/smtpd[29264]: disconnect from unknown[192.208.34.37]
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-remote[29268]: Lost connection
Oct 20 18:31:00 msvsc01-g09np before-remote[29268]: Some error occured
Oct 20 17:31:00 msvsc01-g09np postfix/smtpd[29269]: lost connection after DATA from unknown[127.0.0.1]
Oct 20 17:31:00 msvsc01-g09np postfix/smtpd[29269]: disconnect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: Those don't look like qmail logs, sure you aren't running Postfix?

Comment: It's running from within a Plesk administered environment. Plesk apparently only run QMail so I assumed it was true ^^. A whole bunch of other services are operating alongside it though, so it's possible that Postfix is involved?

Comment: It is possible to install postfix on plesk; however if I recall correctly Plesk bastardized qmail including its log format so this may very well just be qmail.  One other note when dealing with mail server logs it is VERY difficult to decipher the problem when you obfuscate or remove key aspects such as domains.  One of the things we would want to do is look at the SPF record ourselves, but when you hide them domain we don't know where to look.

Comment: Figures - I just obfuscated the email addresses as I didn't want bots to be able to crawl them - you're right - it's Cadbury.com as Scott obviously deduced from the IP addresses ^^

Answer (score 1):

If the domain in question is cadbury.com or cadburyschweppes.com, which is the PTR of the IP address in the logs...then no, the SPF records do not exist.
You might want to look at not failing when there is no SPF record, only when the SPF record does not match the IP address you are talking to.  Not every domain has an SPF record, and it is not a requirement for sending email...